# Section - CSS não funciona

Tags: css, html5

Estou tendo um problema com a section do meu código. Ele está todo sem formatação, limpei o cachê do navegador para ver se funcionava e continua não pegando o CSS.

```css
.newsletter {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3% 4%;
  background-color: #130400;
}

.newsletter h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.newsletter h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.newsletter form {
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<section class="newsletter">
  <h2> Inscreva-se agora! </h2>
  <h3> Receba novidades, dicas e muito mais. </h3>
  <form>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="digite seu email">
    <button> Cadastrar </button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: E no console no navegador dá algum erro?

Comment: o que você quer dizer com sem formatação? veja que coloquei seu código no snippet do site e tem formatação

Comment: @RicardoPontual A formatação não fica fixa no meu elemento 'section' no chrome. Eu consigo visualizar rapidamente o meu css quando aperto F5, depois ele some e fica sem formatação. Também teste aqui no site e aparece a formatação.

Comment: @LeAndrade como verifico isso? Desculpe a pergunta, sou iniciante.

Comment: Se estiver utilizando **Chrome** é a tecla `f12` no teclado. Já tenha em mente isto, tudo que for desenvolver com Html, Css e Javascript, tem que estar com o console aberto. Lá que acusa os erros.

Comment: @LeAndrade Obrigada pela dica. Testei no console e deu o seguinte erro no Html: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

e no CSS:" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "

Comment: Joia Jéssica, é isso aí, o console é o amigo do dev front-end, sempre com ele aberto. Ele mostra o arquivo que está com o erro e também a linha do arquivo que está com erro. Aí é só verificar e consertar.

Comment: Jéssica, o console geralmente mostra erros de JavaScript e rede. Vc deve estar utilizando algum script com erro.